# Security Attributes when creating folder

Tags: c++, security, winapi, directory

I have the following line of code:

```
CreateDirectory(full_folder, attr);
```

Now the attr variable is of type LPSECURITY_ATRRIBUTES and is currently set to NULL.  Can anyone please provide me with a list of all the keywords that are accepted by this variable.  I have searched over the internet but I can't seem to find a proper list.  Maybe I am not searching correctly.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` doesn't take keywords, it is a pointer to a struct. Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379560(v=vs.85).aspx

The useful payload of the struct is a `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR`, an effectively opaque structure that you manipulate using various API functions. Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379561(v=vs.85).aspx